# Why does read.csv read NAs values into a file as character variables?

Tags: r, dataframe, na, read.csv, nas

I need to count the NAs elements in a CSV file containing numeric values and NAs. Using read.csv, r automatically reads them all as character, therefore it's impossibile to detect how many NAs there are. How can i fix that?

Comment: This question is challenging to provide help with since it doesn't provide any information about what the data look like. What do the NA strings look like in the CSV file?ave you tried anything? look into `read.csv(filepath, na.strings = c("NA")` and fill the `c()` with whatever strings you have that represent NA

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

An approach using `which`:

```
x = c(1,2,3)
y = c(6,5,4)
z = c(NA, 8, NA)
df1 <- data.frame(x,y,z)

# which has arr.ind option that returns locations by row/column
NA_idx <- which(is.na(df1) == TRUE, arr.ind = TRUE)
NA_idx
     row col
[1,]   1   3
[2,]   3   3
```

This may not be so directly useful to the 'how many of x', 'how many of NA',
so perhaps

```
length(which(is.na(unlist(df1)==TRUE)))
[1] 2
length(unlist(df1))
[1] 9
length(unlist(df1)) - length(which(is.na(unlist(df1)==TRUE)))
[1] 7
```